# Хочу поменять useragent через селениум, но не получается

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, useragent

Вот мой код, что тут не так?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
user=UserAgent()
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
driver=webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile)
driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/')
```

Вот ошибка

```
 driver=webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile)
File "E:\Python\rabota\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 80, in __init__
ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
File "C:\Users\Вадим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 318, in copytree
names = os.listdir(src)
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not FirefoxProfile
```

Парсинг изучаю недавно, поэтому не знаю, я понимаю, что там связано с firefoxProfile, но что именно не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver=webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile)
```

ты инициализируешь профиль передавая в качестве первого аргумента профиль. а ждешь инстанс драйвера.

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```